# How to check whether a list only contains sorted (w.r.t first element) 2-elements pairs using Scheme?

Tags: list, sorting, scheme

I have written this function to 'check' if the list contains only 2-elements pairs like these: ((1 2)(3 1)(6 2)) --- (sorted based on first elements & no repetition of 1st elements). But I am getting errors, can anyone please give an idea:

```
(define Bag?
(lambda setlist
(cond ((null? setlist) '())
      ((and (pair? (caar setlist)) (= (length (caar setlist)) 2)))
        ((> (caar setlist) 0) (< (caar setlist) (car (cdr (car setlist) ))))
        (else(Bag? (cdr setlist))))
    ))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list traversal doesn't look right. The `lambda` is incorrectly declaring its parameter, and the second condition is wrong, you're not advancing the recursion there.

It'd better to start from scratch. I'll give you a high-level solution in Racket stating what needs to be checked, it's up to you to rewrite it in terms of simpler procedures:

```
(define (bag? setlist)
  (and (apply < (map car setlist))
       (andmap (lambda (e) (and (pair? e) (= 2 (length e))))
               setlist)))
```

The above verifies that the first-elements in each pair appear sorted in ascending order, and that each pair in the list contains exactly two elements.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. yes i think in my function it checks only the first pair. (meaning recursion incorrect.) :/